# How to access a Bash array from a separate, non-child Bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have an array that's created in a Bash script. It takes a bit of work to get the information that I want in there, and it's an array that would be very useful in other scripts. I don't want to duplicate the code through all of the other scripts. The other scripts are not launched as children of this script, so `export` won't be any help here.

Is the only sensible way to get access to this array to source the script which creates it? Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as far as your scenario is concerned `source`-ing is the only way to get that array from script into another non-related shell session. It is also the only way to get a parameter from a script on the current shell session as executing a script will spawn a subshell.

As a workaround for not sourcing on the fly, you can keep the array in every interactive shell session's environment by putting it in `~/.bashrc`, this obviously means that you need to `source` that script at start. So all in all, if you want the array, your only option is `source`-ing sooner or later.